# Select Unselect logic in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement, where there is a checkbox on UI when I select it the first time it gets selected when I click it again it is deselected.

So in logic, I am adding the selected parameter to a set, and if it is already present I remove it for deselecting the parameter.

But this approach is not working when I have to count how many I have total, it gives incorrect values.

I have to implement select multiple and deselect multiple in a web page. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a wrapper? Have a select all/deselect all command link, that command link will call an action which will select/deselect all of the records, then just rerender the table..

Comment: No , I don't have to do a select all and deselect all, I want to select one pass the value to controller and if user selects it again, I E. Clicks it again I wish to remove it from my list in controller, currently I use set and if set contains the element I assume it is deselected and remove it from my list,